# Comment out a Javascript function called in an event of PHTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new to javascript, html, php and started working on it. Today i faced a problem that i need to comment out a javascript function called on an event of a textbox but i am unable to do so . Can you please tell me how can i do that 
Here i am attaching the code part and part which i need to comment out.
Help will be appreciated .

```
 <label class="input"> <input type="text" data-src="gupta"
 id="sudhanshu" class="price" name="sudhanshu"
 onblur="EditMe.calculatePrice('id1'); EditMe.calculateRatio('id1');"
 fieldtype="decimal">
 </label>
```

Here Onblur is the event called in a text box, when this event is called calculatePrice and calculateRatio are javascript functions called, now i want to comment out the second function. what  should be the way to do that.

My tries:

```
/* EditMe.calculateRatio('id1'); */
// EditMe.calculateRatio('id1');"
<!-- EditMe.calculateRatio('id1');"-->
```

not any of these is working.

please reply what should i do

Comment: @KamranAdil you can't place comments within an opening tag

Comment: @charlietfl so it means  i can not comment out the code i want

Comment: no but you can prevent it being used or modify the function being called to check for certain conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the attribute `onblur`

```
$(function(){
    $('#sudhanshu').removeAttr('onblur');
});
```